# Printf() error after entering a function in C

Tags: c

Hi I am having an issue when I enter the AddEmployee() function.

When I enter I want it to print out "First Name" to prompt the user to enter the first name, but it prints out the following:

```
::Add Employee::
First Name:Last Name:
```

So instead of the first name being entered, instead when the user inputs it is actually the last name that is being scanned in.

How do I change the code so that it won't print out

```
First Name:Last Name:
```

But rather

```
First Name: (whatever user enters)
Last Name: (whatever user enters)
```

Here is the code I have written

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Employee{

char FirstName[16];
char LastName[16];
char Address[21];
char ID[4];
char Duration[4];

};

void MainMenu();
void AddEmployee();


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    MainMenu(); 
}


void MainMenu()
{   
    int main_menu = 0;

    printf("::Main Menu::\n");
    printf("1.) Add Employee:\n");
    scanf("%d", &main_menu);

    switch (main_menu) 
    {
        default:
        {
            printf("Invalid Choice!");
            break;
        }
        case(1):
        {
            AddEmployee();
            break;
        }
    }
}


void AddEmployee()
{   
    struct Employee employee;

    printf("::Add Employee::\n");
    printf("First Name:");
    fgets(employee.FirstName, 16, stdin);
    printf("Last Name:");
    fgets(employee.LastName, 16, stdin);

}
```

Comment: This does not consume the `\n`: `scanf("%d", &main_menu);`. So the first `fgets()` is consuming the `\n` from the user's first input.

Comment: @hmjd, why isn't that an answer?

Comment: @CarlNorum, I didn't provide a solution just the reason for the behaviour.

Comment: don't mix `scanf()` and `fgets()`

Comment: @Mike can I ask why I should not mix them?

Comment: @StephenFox - `scanf()` and `fgets()` handle newline characters differently. So if you intermix them you need to be cognitive of which one you used last on what type of input to make sure you handle the newline correctly. It's more headache than it's worth.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &main_menu); switch (main_menu)` is  a problem waiting to happen.  Trying entering 'x' for your menu selection and see what happens.  Use `fgets()/sscanf()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use getchar() to clear the input buffer by reading the '\n' left in buffer.

```
void AddEmployee()
{   
    struct Employee employee;

    printf("::Add Employee::\n");
    printf("First Name:");
    getchar();
    fgets(employee.FirstName, 16, stdin);
    printf("Last Name:");
    fgets(employee.LastName, 16, stdin);

}
```

You can add the getchar() even after the scanf() in main(),

```
 printf("::Main Menu::\n");
    printf("1.) Add Employee:\n");
    scanf("%d", &main_menu);
    getchar();
    switch (main_menu) 
    {
        default:
        {
            printf("Invalid Choice!");
            break;
        }
        case(1):
        {
            AddEmployee();
            break;
        }
```

and it is better to put getchar() right after the original scanf() in main() that resulted in left over `\n` in buffer, considering the comment by @Mike.

Comment: Putting `getchar()` here *assumes* that there will always be something pending on `stdin` before calls to this function. It may be true for the code as written currently, but this is a bad idea to have this assumption in place, it makes much better sense to clear the `'\n'` directly after the original `scanf()` call.

Comment: @Mike ok. i added that to answer